# Como elimino UNIQUE en MySql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Quiero quitar el UNIQUE de per_id pero no me deja

```
CREATE TABLE seguidos (
segi_id         int         PRIMARY KEY         AUTO_INCREMENT,
segi_nomSeg     varchar(50) NOT NULL,
per_id          int         NULL    UNIQUE,
segs_id         int         null,
FOREIGN KEY (per_id) REFERENCES perfil(per_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (segs_id) REFERENCES seguidores(segs_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Ejecuto este query y me lanza error

ALTER TABLE seguidos DROP INDEX per_id

```
Error Code: 1553. Cannot drop index 'per_id': needed in a foreign key constraint
```

Ejecuto este después del error de arriba para quitar la FK y me lanza error

ALTER TABLE seguidos DROP FOREIGN KEY per_id;

```
Error Code: 1091. Can't DROP 'per_id'; check that column/key exists
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9172188/5215609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ver el nombre de tu llave foránea puedes ejecutar:

```
show create table seguidos;
```

Te mostrará algo así:

```
'CREATE TABLE `seguidos` (\n  `segi_id` int(11) NOT NULL
 AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  `segi_nomSeg` varchar(50) NOT NULL,\n  `per_id` 
 int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `segs_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,\n  PRIMARY 
 KEY
(`segi_id`),\n  KEY `segs_id` (`segs_id`),\n  CONSTRAINT 
`seguidos_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`segs_id`) REFERENCES `seguidores` 
 (`segs_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE\n) ENGINE=InnoDB 
 DEFAULT 
 CHARSET=utf8'
```

luego debes eliminar tu llave foránea:

```
 ALTER TABLE seguidos DROP FOREIGN key seguidos_ibfk_1 #aqui el nombre de llave foránea
```

Una vez eliminada la LLave foranea ya puedes eliminar tu indice:

```
ALTER TABLE seguidos DROP index per_id
```

Comment: Cuando intento borar FK me sale el error que mencione 
Error Code: 1091. Can't DROP 'per_id'; check that column/key exists

Comment: tu llave foranea se llama algo como `eguidos_ibfk_1` , per_id es tu campo

Comment: ohh si es que puse el 2 en vez del uno men. Muchas gracias crack

Comment: Solo que primero se tiene que ejecutar el comando SHOW CREATE TABLE <nombre de la tabla> y de ahí sacar el nombre de FK y ya hacer lo que pusiste en ese orden pero primero va el show...

Comment: buen punto, editare la respuesta